# Programming with SurfaceView and thread strategy for game development

Tags: android, multithreading, android-activity, surfaceview

I am using a SurfaceView and a rendering thread to develop a game based on structure like LunarLander.

However, I faced many problems, and here I want to point them all out. I wish anyone who want to develop a game won't need to struggle with them anymore. And anyone who have a better idea of the structure can share their experiences, because I am still new to android and is eager to learn :)

[1] The function `thread.start()` should not be called more than once.

Many articles mentioned to create a thread when surface is created, in order to render again after activity paused using the method :

```
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // start the thread here so that we don't busy-wait in run()
    // waiting for the surface to be created
    if (thread.getState() == Thread.State.TERMINATED)
    {
        thread = new LunarThread(getHolder(), getContext(), getHandler());
    }
    thread.setRunning(true);
    thread.start();
}
```

You can see that if the thread isn't terminated and the function is called, the activity crashes.

[2] If you pressed the "power" or the "red phone" button, or the phone is idle for a few minutes, the activity would be `onPause()` state, but the thread is still running. That is a really bad practice, so I need to find out a method to let the thread stop, and start again when `onResume()`.

[3] If the screen lock is portrait / landscape, and your game is sticked to the other orientation, the screen lock forced you to "orient" once. That means to start the activity once more. I still can not find a solution to it. (as I mentioned in [Android screen orientation bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4050177/android-screen-orientation-bug))

Here are my code to fix those problems:

UIThread

```
public class UIThread extends Activity
{
    private gameView gameview;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        gameview = (gameView) findViewById(R.id.gameview);
    }
    protected void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();
        Log.v("MY_ACTIVITY", "onPause");
        gameview.terminateThread();
        System.gc();
    }
    protected void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        Log.v("MY_ACTIVITY", "onResume");
        if (gameview.surfaceCreated == true)
        {
            gameview.createThread(gameview.getHolder());
        }
    }
}
```

GameView

```
public class gameView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback
{
    boolean surfaceCreated;
    class gameThread extends Thread{}
    public gameView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);context.getResources();
            Log.v("MY_ACTIVITY", "gameView");
        surfaceCreated = false;
    }
    public void createThread (SurfaceHolder holder)
    {
            thread = new gameThread(holder);
        thread.run = true;
        thread.start();
    }
    public void terminateThread ()
    {
        thread.run = false;
        try
        {
            thread.join();
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            Log.e("FUNCTION", "terminateThread corrupts");
        }       
    }
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder)
    {
        Log.v("MY_ACTIVITY", "surfaceCreated");
        if (surfaceCreated == false)
        {
            createThread(holder);
            surfaceCreated = true;
        }
    }
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) 
    {
        Log.v("MY_ACTIVITY", "surfaceDestroyed");
        surfaceCreated = false;
    }
}
```

Manifest

```
<activity android:name=".UIThread"
          android:screenOrientation="landscape"
          android:configChanges="orientation">
```

I use `onResume()` instead of `surfaceCreated()` to new thread. And I set a boolean `surfaceCreated` to know that `onResume()` comes from the first time application is created, or comes from the "screen off" situation.

So the thread die every time `onPause()` is called. Seems to be a good practice. Another way to let the thread stop then resume again is to synchronize an object and call wait / notify. But I don't know it is better or not.

Is there any better way to control the rendering thread?

Comment: Possibly relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567641/should-the-renderingthread-of-a-surfaceview-have-the-same-life-cycle-as-the-view/21684399#21684399

Answer (score 3):

the solution is here

```
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder){

            if (plot_thread.getState() == Thread.State.TERMINATED) {
                plot_thread = new WaveformPlotThread(getHolder(), this);
                plot_thread.setRunning(true);
                plot_thread.start();
            }
            else {
                plot_thread.setRunning(true);
                plot_thread.start();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

I hope it can help

```
@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

   //if it is the first time the thread starts
   if(thread.getState() == Thread.State.NEW){
    thread.setRunning(true);//riga originale
    thread.start();//riga originale
   }

   //after a pause it starts the thread again
   else
   if (thread.getState() == Thread.State.TERMINATED){
       thread = new MainThread(getHolder(), this);
       thread.setRunning(true);
       thread.start();  // Start a new thread
       }
   }
```

and this

```
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
    Log.d(TAG, "Pausing...");
    MainThread.running=false;//this is the value for stop the loop in the run()
    super.onPause();
    }
```

Comment: Boris thanks a lot for your answer its simple & working after long days of searching.

Comment: I used this code. My problem in some devices is the surface takes time to be created; some second. Any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

I've been dealing with the same issue. I'm learning about game development on Android and also based my first project on the Lunar Lander example. I found that the [SpriteMethodTest](http://code.google.com/p/apps-for-android/source/browse/trunk/SpriteMethodTest) project created by Chris Pruett implements a much better approach in terms of thread management. It's all about using notify and wait methods, though. I couldn't tell whether it's better than your solution or not.