# Android Camera and SurfaceView: Correct way to release

Tags: android-camera

I wanted to know what is the best practice for writing the SurfaceView surfaceDestroyed method and surfaceCreated method, and also the onPause and onResume methods of the Activity using the  camera? There are several posts but none of them seem to help.

Here is the code:

SurfaceCreated

```
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    try {
        Log.d(TAG,"Surface Created");
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        mCamera.startPreview();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

SurfaceDestroyed

```
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    this.getHolder().removeCallback(this);
    mCamera.stopPreview();
    mCamera.release();
}
```

Activity onResume

```
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
    Log.d(TAG,"onResume Called");
    if (mCamera==null){
    mCamera=getCameraInstance();
    }
    initializeCamera(mCamera);      
}
```

Activity onPause

```
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Log.d(TAG,"onPause Called");
    if(mCamera!=null){
        mCamera.stopPreview();
        mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
        mPreview.getHolder().removeCallback(mPreview);
        preview.removeView(mPreview);
        mCamera.release();
        mCamera = null;
    }
}
```

In initializeCamera, I do the following:

```
private void initializeCamera(Camera mCamera) {
    mPreview = new InternalCameraPreview(this, mCamera);
    preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
    preview.addView(mPreview);

}
```

With this setup, I get the error Method Called Before Release() when I run the app. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: FWIW, some general thoughts about the SurfaceView lifecycle are here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567641/should-the-renderingthread-of-a-surfaceview-have-the-same-life-cycle-as-the-view/21684399#21684399

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be like this:

```
@Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        if (mCamera != null){
            //              mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
            mPreview.getHolder().removeCallback(mPreview);
            releaseMediaRecorder();
            mCamera.release();        // release the camera for other applications
            mCamera = null;

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (mCamera == null) {
            mCamera=getCameraInstance();
            mPreview = new CameraPreview(this.getActivity(), mCamera);
            preview.addView(mPreview);
        }
    }
```

Nothing is needed in surfaceDestroyed